# With vs. lapply - why does with not work here?

Tags: r, lapply, with-statement

I am trying to learn R and can't really figure out when to use *with* appropriately. I was thinking about this example:

The goal is to convert "dstr" and "died" in the whole dataframe "stroke" (in the ISwR database) to date format in several ways (just for practice). I've managed to do it like this:

```
#applying a function to the whole data frame - use the fact that data frames are lists actually
rawstroke=read.csv2(system.file("rawdata","stroke.csv",package="ISwR"),na.strings=".")
names(rawstroke)=tolower(names(rawstroke))
ix=c("dstr","died")
rawstroke[ix]=lapply(rawstroke[ix],as.Date,format="%d.%m.%Y")
head(rawstroke)
```

However, when I try using with function it does not give data frame as output, but only writes the definition of the function myfun. Here is the code I tried.

```
myfun=function(x)
{y=as.Date(x,format="%d.%m.%Y")
 return(y)}
rawstroke=read.csv2(system.file("rawdata","stroke.csv",package="ISwR"),na.strings=".")
names(rawstroke)=tolower(names(rawstroke))
ix=c("dstr","died")
bla=with(rawstroke[ix],myfun)
head(bla)
```

If somebody could help me with this, it would be great.

Comment: You seem to think that `with()` somehow loops over the environment variables, which it doesn't.  It is not even close to the same thing as `lapply()`.  Have a look at the source, `with.default` in the console.  It is basically just a simple and clean way to access an environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this doesn't seem like a job for `with`. To use your function here, you'd just replace `as.Date` in your first code with `myfun` and remove the format parameter, like

```
rawstroke[ix]=lapply(rawstroke[ix], myfun)
```

`with` is used to more cleanly access variables in data frames and environments. For example, instead of

```
t.test(dat$x, dat$y)
```

you could do

```
with(dat, t.test(x, y))
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically I can use functions in with only if I can explicitely write them down? I mean, for example with(stroke,age*2) works nicely (loops over the elements). But if want to use functions I defined I should use lapply?

Comment: Sounds like a new question, it's not clear from this why that would loop over the elements. `with` doesn't do looping, it's for any expression at all, it just looks for the variables not only in the global environment but also in whatever you're doing that expression "with."

Comment: Thanks. I think I got it. Well in a way I thought it does looping in a sense that it applies the operation element wise. If I understood it correctly it somehow interprets if the operation is element wise or column wise so it is  flexible in that sense.

Comment: Not really... Maybe you're noticing the effects of vectorized operations? That happens whether or not you use `with`.